# How to iterate this structure Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> and pass its values into a method?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, hashset

I would like to iterate through this structure `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` and pass its values into a method using **Java Stream** API.

Let's say I have a function

> doSomething(String a, String b, Set  c)

and I need to call it for the values of the structure above.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> mySet1 = Set.of("A", "B");
    Set<String> mySet2 = Set.of("C", "D");
    Map<String, Set<String>> helperSet = new HashMap<>();
    helperSet.put("1557491", mySet1);  
    helperSet.put("1557492", mySet2);  
    myMap.put("1165624", helperSet);

    List<MyObject> details = myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> doSomething(
                    e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                            .map(d -> d.getKey()).iterator().next(),
                    e.getKey(),
                    e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                            .map(f -> f.getValue().iterator().next())
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is what I have written so far, unfortunately it doesn't work, it only manages to pass the values of the first set (mySet1).

I am quite new to Java 8. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a stream within a stream:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e1 -> e1.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .map(e2 -> doSomething(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey(), e2.getValue()))
            .collect(toList())
    ).flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough, Bohemian! Appreciate it!